# Should I continue learning C# with Windows Forms or WPF Applications?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am starting to learn c# and wanted to create an actual app which one of the two would you start with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would learn WPF.  We use a lot of Winforms, but we're in the process of migrating to WPF.  I think that's a more future proof set of skills.  [WPF Virtual Labs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa740389.aspx) are a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend WPF - it is now very mature and well supported.   Of course, winforms is still supported and some new development is being done for it.  However,  WPF is significantly more sophisticated and powerful.   Almost as importantly, the tool support for it is MUCH better than for WPF.

Here are some links for you.

- [A Guided Tour of Windows Presentation Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480221.aspx)
- [Windows Client .NET](http://windowsclient.net/)
- [WPF vs Windows Forms](http://mdavey.wordpress.com/2007/09/05/wpf-vs-windows-forms/)

Answer (score 1):

My rule of thumb is to choose the most recent technology that doesn't require your users to go through extra effort.  If you have to support Windows XP, then WinForms is the way to go as it doesn't require XP users to install .NET updates.  If you don't have to worry about XP, then WPF is probably the ready to go.

Comment: And given the disaster known as "Vista", XP will be around for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I would say learn both to have a stronger foundation of knowledge and be able to work with legacy code, but put more effort into WPF because it will eventually replace WinForms.

Comment: I can only learn one thing at a time or at least start with one.. I have now decided to first take a closer look at WPF ;)

Comment: I'd disagree with this - just learn WPF. WinForms is really based on 20+ year old technology and the model has been completely replaced for WPF. I'd avoid learning WinForms if you can.

Answer (score -1):

The basics of either are much the same -- WPF offers a lot more features by way of declarative UI definition and skinning/theming, and a slightly different set of layout techniques.  While you're at the "Hello world!" stages, it makes little difference -- certainly less than using either GTK# or the Swing implementation in VJSSupUILib would.

Comment: I don't agree- WPF and Winforms are very, very different.   Developing for WPF is very different form developing for Winfroms.